# Backflow prevention fixture on my sprinkler system has started leaking -- is teflon tape the appropriate fix?

Tags: plumbing, leak, irrigation, backflow-preventer

The backflow valve on my irrigation system has developed a minor leak at the threads I am pointing to. It's outside and not super fast, so not super urgent, but I would like to get it fixed eventually. Looking at the assembly, I see that every other threaded connection has teflon tape, but the two connections on the backflow unit do not.

I can't speak to why this might be, but since it's threaded I assume the appropriate fix is to unscrew it, slap on some teflon tape, and put it all back together. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: Does not look like any tape was used there(odd).  All other fittings seems to have tape except those two, so there might be a reason(or the guy ran out of tape).

Comment: Properly installed the tape should be fine.